# Kentico, how to update objects via REST?

Tags: rest, kentico

I'm working with Kentico 9's REST capabilities.

I can create a user object by submitting a POST to the following URL pattern:

```
POST <host>/rest/cms.user/site/<sitename>
```

But I also need to update a user. According to their documentation, you should be able to do this:

```
PUT <host>/rest/cms.user/site/<sitename>/<userid>
```

But I receive a 404 doing this. Any ideas? Is the documentation wrong? I get better results if I change the update to a POST, but it still says it's a forbidden operation.

Comment: I received an update from Kentico support saying that I need to use the following method, but I get a 404 from this as well:

    PUT <host>/rest/cms.user/site/<sitename>/<userGUID>

So it appears that this functionality does not work at all. Does anyone have any good resources for creating custom endpoints that work with Kentico? I may need to skip around REST to accomplish user updates.

Comment: Don't give up too soon. The updates work for sure, you're just doing something wrong...Have you tried the solution I posted below?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me...

Comment: I received a response from Kentico's tech support, and they confirmed that this didn't work either. Then I received a followup which instructed me to add the following line to the root web.config file:

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

Why this isn't enabled by default, I have no idea. It's really strange that this would allow you to create objects via rest, but not perform updates. But this was the key.

Comment: Yep, you have to have that in your config. It's also in the documentation https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+the+REST+service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modules tag in the site's root web.config file needs to be modified like so:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Answer (score 3):

Use just:

- `PUT <host>/rest/cms.user/<id>`

Or:

- use codename or GUID for `<id>` (not int) in your original request.

See the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Managing+objects+using+REST#ManagingobjectsusingREST-Updatingexistingobjects).